# Default theme as shinyDashboardThemeDIY

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

`dashboardthemes` allows to conveniently build custom themes for `shinydashboard` through the use of the `shinyDashboardThemeDIY` function.

On https://github.com/nik01010/dashboardthemes/tree/master/R there is a `shinyDashboardThemeDIY` syntax for all the custom themes used to showcase `dashboardthemes` there.

However, I'd like to work out of the *default* theme and customize it, and I cannot find the `shinyDashboardThemeDIY` syntax for the *default* `shinydashboard`, which looks as follows:

### [image: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html]

Does anyone knows where to find it or has anyone been able to reconstruct it?

To clarify, I am looking for a piece of code like the following:

```
shinyDashboardThemeDIY(
  
    ### general
    appFontFamily = "Arial"
    ,appFontColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,primaryFontColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,infoFontColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,successFontColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,warningFontColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,dangerFontColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,bodyBackColor = "rgb(248,248,248)"
  
    ### header
    ,logoBackColor = "rgb(23,103,124)"
  
    ,headerButtonBackColor = "rgb(238,238,238)"
    ,headerButtonIconColor = "rgb(75,75,75)"
    ,headerButtonBackColorHover = "rgb(210,210,210)"
    ,headerButtonIconColorHover = "rgb(0,0,0)"
  
    ,headerBackColor = "rgb(238,238,238)"
    ,headerBoxShadowColor = "#aaaaaa"
    ,headerBoxShadowSize = "2px 2px 2px"
  
    ### sidebar
    ,sidebarBackColor = cssGradientThreeColors(
      direction = "down"
      ,colorStart = "rgb(20,97,117)"
      ,colorMiddle = "rgb(56,161,187)"
      ,colorEnd = "rgb(3,22,56)"
      ,colorStartPos = 0
      ,colorMiddlePos = 50
      ,colorEndPos = 100
    )
    ,sidebarPadding = 0
  
    ,sidebarMenuBackColor = "transparent"
    ,sidebarMenuPadding = 0
    ,sidebarMenuBorderRadius = 0
  
    ,sidebarShadowRadius = "3px 5px 5px"
    ,sidebarShadowColor = "#aaaaaa"
  
    ,sidebarUserTextColor = "rgb(255,255,255)"
  
    ,sidebarSearchBackColor = "rgb(55,72,80)"
    ,sidebarSearchIconColor = "rgb(153,153,153)"
    ,sidebarSearchBorderColor = "rgb(55,72,80)"
  
    ,sidebarTabTextColor = "rgb(255,255,255)"
    ,sidebarTabTextSize = 13
    ,sidebarTabBorderStyle = "none none solid none"
    ,sidebarTabBorderColor = "rgb(35,106,135)"
    ,sidebarTabBorderWidth = 1
  
    ,sidebarTabBackColorSelected = cssGradientThreeColors(
      direction = "right"
      ,colorStart = "rgba(44,222,235,1)"
      ,colorMiddle = "rgba(44,222,235,1)"
      ,colorEnd = "rgba(0,255,213,1)"
      ,colorStartPos = 0
      ,colorMiddlePos = 30
      ,colorEndPos = 100
    )
    ,sidebarTabTextColorSelected = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,sidebarTabRadiusSelected = "0px 20px 20px 0px"
  
    ,sidebarTabBackColorHover = cssGradientThreeColors(
      direction = "right"
      ,colorStart = "rgba(44,222,235,1)"
      ,colorMiddle = "rgba(44,222,235,1)"
      ,colorEnd = "rgba(0,255,213,1)"
      ,colorStartPos = 0
      ,colorMiddlePos = 30
      ,colorEndPos = 100
    )
    ,sidebarTabTextColorHover = "rgb(50,50,50)"
    ,sidebarTabBorderStyleHover = "none none solid none"
    ,sidebarTabBorderColorHover = "rgb(75,126,151)"
    ,sidebarTabBorderWidthHover = 1
    ,sidebarTabRadiusHover = "0px 20px 20px 0px"
  
    ### boxes
    ,boxBackColor = "rgb(255,255,255)"
    ,boxBorderRadius = 5
    ,boxShadowSize = "0px 1px 1px"
    ,boxShadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.1)"
    ,boxTitleSize = 16
    ,boxDefaultColor = "rgb(210,214,220)"
    ,boxPrimaryColor = "rgba(44,222,235,1)"
    ,boxInfoColor = "rgb(210,214,220)"
    ,boxSuccessColor = "rgba(0,255,213,1)"
    ,boxWarningColor = "rgb(244,156,104)"
    ,boxDangerColor = "rgb(255,88,55)"
  
    ,tabBoxTabColor = "rgb(255,255,255)"
    ,tabBoxTabTextSize = 14
    ,tabBoxTabTextColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,tabBoxTabTextColorSelected = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,tabBoxBackColor = "rgb(255,255,255)"
    ,tabBoxHighlightColor = "rgba(44,222,235,1)"
    ,tabBoxBorderRadius = 5
  
    ### inputs
    ,buttonBackColor = "rgb(245,245,245)"
    ,buttonTextColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
    ,buttonBorderColor = "rgb(200,200,200)"
    ,buttonBorderRadius = 5
  
    ,buttonBackColorHover = "rgb(235,235,235)"
    ,buttonTextColorHover = "rgb(100,100,100)"
    ,buttonBorderColorHover = "rgb(200,200,200)"
  
    ,textboxBackColor = "rgb(255,255,255)"
    ,textboxBorderColor = "rgb(200,200,200)"
    ,textboxBorderRadius = 5
    ,textboxBackColorSelect = "rgb(245,245,245)"
    ,textboxBorderColorSelect = "rgb(200,200,200)"
  
    ### tables
    ,tableBackColor = "rgb(255,255,255)"
    ,tableBorderColor = "rgb(240,240,240)"
    ,tableBorderTopSize = 1
    ,tableBorderRowSize = 1
  
  )
```

except it reproduces the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

These theme definitions override the default theme CSS styles definitions. You can check the [CreateTheme_shinyDashboardThemeDIY.R](https://github.com/nik01010/dashboardthemes/blob/master/R/CreateTheme_shinyDashboardThemeDIY.R) file of the dashboardthemes package to get the list of specific CSS rules replaced by these definitions.

For example `,headerBackColor = "rgb(238,238,238)"` replaces the default header background color with the  `.skin-blue .main-header .navbar` rules:

```
    .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
      background: ', headerBackColor, ';
      box-shadow: ', headerBoxShadowSize, ' ', headerBoxShadowColor, ';
    }
```

Then if you want to find the default values of these CSS rules, they are mostly located in the [_all-skins.css](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/blob/master/inst/AdminLTE/_all-skins.css) file from the shinydashboard package (from the AdminLTE template).

For example, you'll find the default header background color there:

```
.skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
  background-color: #3c8dbc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a good clue. However it is difficult to match all the parameters. Maybe someone has already done it and is able to share? That would be much appreciated